# TensorFlow GPU linux installation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

This is the error I am getting:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me how to install step by step in ubuntu 16.04 platform?

Comment: Refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35735162/6521116) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36159194/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You lost the environment variables. Refer to [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1501). For more refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735162/6521116).

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda then run this command in your anaconda prompt

`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

This will also install the `cuda toolkit` and `cudnn` for you and you are good to go